# How to create a new table to rearrange the columns in RStudio?

Tags: r

I am new to RStudio, and my goal is to create a new table that sums each category (of Application status) from the raw data sample. I have looked to similar questions to this, but I got even more confused. I have provided the code below (I know it's wrong). I appreciate all the help! Any resources for RStudio is greatly appreciated as well.

Raw Data Sample:

| Student_ID | Application_Status0 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Verified |
| 2 | Complete |
| 3 | Not Complete |
| 4 | Verified |
| 5 | Complete |
| 6 | Not Compete |
| 7 | Complete |
| 8 | Verified |

Desired Table:

| Application_Status | # of Students |
| --- | --- |
| Verified | 100 |
| Complete | 209 |
| Not Complete | 385 |

Code (in chunk):

````
```{r}
df
sum(df$Student_ID)
sum(df$Application_Status0)

df1=as.table()

df1
````

Comment: Try `aggregate(Student_ID ~ Application_Status0, df1, length)`. This is definitely a duplicate but I'm not find it right now.

Comment: I tried both methods. Unfortunately, it did not work for me. I got errors: "The table does not coerce". I am sure there is a very similar question that may answer my question, but I do not see it either.

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `dput(head(df))` or just `dput(df)`, someone will be able to answer immediately.

Comment: Try this: `table(df$Application_Status0)`